# Android reading from .txt File created in src folder

Tags: android

I am using this to get my File located in src folder src/file1.txt

```
InputStream is = openFileInput("file1.txt");
```

and using BufferedReader to Read but its throwing

> FileNotFoundException :data/data/package/files/file1.txt

same thing occurs with

```
URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file1.txt");
```

Any idea?/

Comment: put it into your raw-folder.

Comment: move it to assests folder and use `InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("file1.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

Your src folder doesn't and won't exist on your emulator or device; it only exists on your host machine. If you want to read in a file delivered with your app, put it in either your raw or assets folder.

Answer (score -1):

can try this code...................................

String packageName = context.getPackageName();

DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases/";

path=DB_PATH+DB_PATH;

```
   private void copyDatabase() {
    try {
        InputStream dbInputStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);//Read data..........
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream dbOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);// write data............
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int readCount = 0;
        while ((readCount = dbInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            dbOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }

        dbInputStream.close();
        dbOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not in any way an answer to the question asked.